# Summing Ints less than an Argument in J

Tags: sum, j

I'm using J for this algo, it's meant to take the sum of all positive ints less than or equal to the argument.

```
  sum=: + +@:+/&:i.
```

which has usage case:

```
   sum 3
6
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? I'm still new to J, and I just was wondering how y'all would implement this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want the sum (`+/`) of (`@:`) the list of integers (`i.`) up to the argument. So just write that:

```
sum2 =: +/ @: i.
```

and keeping in mind that the list goes from 0 to (arg - 1), increment the argument before taking the list:

```
sum2 =: +/ @: i. @ >:
```

It's rather efficient:

```
timespacex'sum2 1e5'
0.000327 525376
timespacex'sum 1e5'
0.033216 525440
```

*The most efficient way, of course, is to use the formula `-:@(*>:)`*